# Use Google Calendar API in User Control : System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, google-api-dotnet-client

I fail when trying to use the Google API v3 in a user control.

Steps:

- Create a new project in Visual Studio Express 2013 Update 4. Target framework: .NET 4.5 (tried 4.0 too)
- Install NuGet package "[Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 Client Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)" and all and all dependencies
- Add new User Control "MyControl"
- In MyCalendar_Load add the following line: CalendarService service = new ServiceCalendar();
- Add using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;

So the code of my control looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;



namespace Google_Calendar_Test
{
    public partial class MyCalendar : UserControl
    {
        public MyCalendar()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MyCalendar_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalendarService service = new CalendarService();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I compile my solution so I get my newly created MyControl. When I try to put the control on the form the following error message appears:

[image]

System.IO.FileNotFoundException / Could not load file or assembly Google.Apis,

In the form I can add the CalendarService and start it without any problems. I'm puzzled.

**Update**

The version in the error message (V 1.0.0.23042) doesn't match to the version NuGet installed (V 1.0.0.26011). But this doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Maybe setting "Copy Locally" for the Google* assemblies to `true` does help?

Comment: Agreed try setting the Dlls to Copy Local or add them to GAC

Comment: Copy Locally is set for all Google* assemblies, I checked it. (this is set by default anyway). Zlib.Portable isn't set to true, changed it, but it doesn't solved the problem.

Comment: I just tested your code and it does compile. It doesn't do anything since you haven't added authentication yet.  But there are no errors.  all you need to do is Install-Package Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 That will get you everything you need

Comment: @DalmTo: yes, as I wrote I can compile the solution. But I can't add the control to my form. Then I get the error.
This is a simple example to reproduce. In my 'real' project I have the authentication implemented with the JSON file and it does work (ready calendars and more) but not in is user control.